# How to add icons/images to the legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to add icon/images into the legend box as the picture attached (source: https://esajournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/eap.1973)

Does anyone know about this thing using `ggplot`?

[image]

Comment: Look at key_glyph() in ggplot2_3.2.0 as a starting point.